# Proof of work - does the equipment matter?

Tags: hash, mining-hardware, hashpower, proof-of-work

It technically doesn’t matter whether I am using a super computer or a laptop to do the proof of work, it’s simply that with a super computer I can go through the attempts much faster, which means I have a higher chance of solving the problem before anyone else and therefore claiming the reward, right?

Comment: Isn't that the only thing that *does* matter?

Comment: How can it be that you have to generate a hash below a certain number if there are letters in the hash, and not just numbers?

Comment: You're confusing *values* of numbers with *representations* of numbers. You can represent numbers with letters if you want, the letter "A" can stand for the number ten (as can "10", "ten", "xxxxxxxxxx", "one more than nine" and a dozen other things). It's still a number. It can still be compared. We mean a hash with a lower *value*, regardless of how you choose to represent the number (as digits in base ten, in hexadecimal, or in scratches on a wooden board, it doesn't matter).

Answer (score 2):

Right.

The proof of work is computing 2 SHA256 of a sequence of bytes that represent the block header to find a value lower than a target. It doesn't matter if the 2 hashes are computed by an ASIC, a CPU, a GPU or a [HP-48](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP-48). What matters is the number of hashes you can compute per unit of time.

That's why the power of mining hardware is measure in MH/s, GH/s or TH/s (mega, giga and terahashes per second).

Comment: Cool thanks. But How can it be that you have to generate a hash below a certain number if there are letters in the hash, and not just numbers?

Comment: The hash is encoded in hexadecimal (base 16), you could translate it to base 10 if you want to have a value that's easier to compare for you.